# One VGA port, how do I connect both a VGA and DVI to it?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, input-device

I have a monitor with one VGA port. I want to be able to plug in a VGA and a DVI into that monitor, only one input will be used at a time.

It's a hassle to undo the knobs each time I want to switch input.

Comment: So get a VGA switch?

Comment: What happened to the DVI output?  You accepted an answer that deals with two VGA outputs.  Please clarify the requirements in your question.

Comment: @fixer1234, I can use an adaptor to go from DVI to VGA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a VGA switcher. They are cheap and plentiful. If you get a device that is marketed as a KVM Switch it will also switch your keyboard/video/mouse inputs between two computers (if that's what you want as well).

[Example amazon search](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=vga%20switcher)

[image]